# How to pass a missing optional parameter to a VBA method from PowerShell

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I have a Word (Office 2013) document and I need to split each page of the document into a separate PDF.  So, I put this together using PowerShell.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $true

$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($SourceFile)

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo -le 50; $pageNo++)
{
    $OutputFile = $OutputDirectory + "\MyFile_" + $pageNo + ".pdf"

    $Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($OutputFile, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat]::wdExportFormatPDF, $false, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor]::wdExportOptimizeForPrint, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange]::wdExportFromTo, $pageNo, $pageNo, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem]::wdExportDocumentContent, $false, $false, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks]::wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, $false, $true, $false, $null)
}

$Doc.Close()    
$Word.Quit()
```

I've made it as far as the **last parameter**, which is expecting this a reference to this.

```
[ref] System.Object FixedFormatExtClassPtr
```

I've tried passing in $null, 0, each with or without [ref], but I get this error:

> Argument: '15' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference.
>   Use [ref].

Any ideas on what I need to pass in for this last parameter?  Or, is there an easier way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong.  For the last parameter, I needed to use System.Type.Missing.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $true

$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($SourceFile)
$fixedFromatExtClassPtr = [System.Type]::Missing

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo -le 50; $pageNo++)
{
    $OutputFile = $OutputDirectory + "\MyFile_" + $pageNo + ".pdf"

    $Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($OutputFile, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat]::wdExportFormatPDF, $false, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor]::wdExportOptimizeForPrint, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange]::wdExportFromTo, $pageNo, $pageNo, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem]::wdExportDocumentContent, $false, $false, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks]::wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, $false, $true, $false, [ref]$fixedFromatExtClassPtr)
}

$Doc.Close()    
$Word.Quit()
```