# How do I emulate Nothing parameter in VBA inside a Powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I have Excel VBA code that calls Workbook.XmlImport()

```
result=ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport( _
        URL:=strXML, _
        ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
     )
```

Note that the second parameter is Nothing -- no import map specified.

When I try to move this to PowerShell, I don't know how to specify Nothing.

```
$xl=New-Object -com Excel.Application;
$wb=$xl.Workbooks.Add();
$ws=$wb.WorkSheets.Item(1);
$r=$ws.Range('$A$1');
$XML='blahblah.xml';
$result=$wb.XmlImport($XML, ????, $True, $r);
$wb.SaveAs('filename.xlsx', 51, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $False, $False, 1);
$xl.Quit()
```

If I use `$null`, `[Type]::Missing`, or `[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value` in place of ???? above, I get:

> Argument: '2' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference.
>   Use [ref].

Using [ref]$null in place of ???? above, I get:

> Exception calling "XmlImport" with "4" argument(s): "Type mismatch.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

What can I pass into the second parameter to mimic the Nothing in VBA?

Comment: Why not try `[Type]::Missing` like you did in the `SaveAs` method. Or `[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value` ?

Comment: How about using a variable of `[System.Type]::Missing`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133373/how-to-pass-a-missing-optional-parameter-to-a-vba-method-from-powershell)?

Comment: `[ref]$out = $null; $result = $wb.XmlImport($xml, $out, $true, $r)` is what you'd normally do here. I don't know why this is giving you a type mismatch.

Comment: @RikSportel The `System` namespace can be omitted, so `[System.Type]::Missing` is the same as `[Type]::Missing`, which the OP already tried.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I this working for you and if so which PS/Excel versions? It is not for me on Excel 2013. PoweShell v5.1 gives `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, v2 gives `XmlImport : Exception calling "XmlImport" with "4" argument(s): "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"`

Comment: @gms0ulman Sorry, I didn't mean to make it sound like it was working for me. I was getting the same error when I tested. I just can't explain it, b/c from my understanding it should be working.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Agreed,  from my understanding of `Nothing` being a null reference.  It behaves as I'd expected in PowerShell but is rejected by `XmlImport`... suspect it's an interop limitation; not finding much info to support/dispute this